# Limiting entries object when using as json_encode

Tags: templating, entries, json

I'm building a JSON array of several thousand entries using the following entries query:

`{% set services = craft.entries.section('services').asArray().all() %}`

The problem is there some private info is visible within the JSON and can be viewed in the browser source (not to mention the result is HUGE.

`let services = {{ services | json_encode | raw }};`

Is there a parameter similar to [ids()](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#ids) where I can specify only the title, url, and ID?
If not, what's the best Twig way to reduce this array to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries):

> Element queries are specialized query builders under the hood, so they
> support most of the same methods provided by craft\db\Query.

...So, in your case you could use `select()` to only select the fields you want:

`{% set services = craft.entries.section('services').asArray().select(['title','id','url']).all() %}`

Comment: Thanks! I knew this was possible. The `.select()` example on the page just takes you to the Yii docs. I ws adding select() before the asArray().

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
{% set svcarray = craft.entries.section('services').select('content.id,content.title,elements_sites.slug,elements_sites.uri').asArray().all() %}
```

For whatever reason this ended up throwing an exception:

```
{% set svcarray = craft.entries.section('services').asArray().select(['title','id','url']).all() %}
```

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is
> ambiguous